# Encountered a sub-selection on the query, but the store doesn't have an object reference Apollo Link State

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

This is my main query to get all data from a server.

[image: Query to get data from server]

Then I would like to set this in Apollo link state.

To set in link state here's my resolver.

[image: resolver for link state]

This is my client/cache query to get previous cache state.

[image: local client/cache query]

I don't know where I'm missing anything on this.

> ApolloError.js:37 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error:
>   Encountered a sub-selection on the query, but the store doesn't have
>   an object reference. This should never happen during normal use unless
>   you have custom code that is directly manipulating the store; please
>   file an issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Not sure why. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Same here, no idea when this bug started occurring

Comment: I'm also getting a very similar issue. It started out of nowhere it seems. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Same here, appeared suddenly

Comment: Had the same issue on node > 10, switched to 8 everything is working fine.

Comment: @Gintoki I am already using node v8.10.0 and i am facing this problem

Answer (score 1):

This error might be happening due to `apollo-cache-inmemory` package version. Try updating the package to the latest version:

`npm update apollo-cache-inmemory`

This github thread is trying to track the issue and updating the package seems to work just fine: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4125

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a query setup to fetch a nested object, but you are not requesting anything from that nested object.

In this example, *hero* has two properties, *name* of type `string` and *ultimateAbility* of type `Ability`.
`Ability` has *name*: `string` and *cooldown*: `number`.

With that in mind, the following might give you that error because we are requesting *ultimateAbility* (our nested object) but we are not telling graph what we want from it:

```
{
  hero {
    name
    ultimateAbility
  }
}
```

The correct approach would be to just add which props you want from *ultimateAbility*:

```
{
  hero {
    name
    ultimateAbility {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

My background: I went through this recently and after digging through lots of PRs my team nailed down to this.